# How to add a row in table with varchar type column, a word with inverted comma?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table **dbo.AccountTypes** with following two columns

```
AccountTypeId    int         not null
AccountTypeName  varchar(50) not null
```

I want to add a row with values *1* and *Partner's Capital A/c* for the respective columns. I tried following insert command but it does not work.

```
insert into dbo.AccountTypes (AccountTypeId, AccountTypeName)
values (1, "Partner's Capital A/c")
```

Please note inverted comma in the word **Partner's Capital A/c**

But it fails. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace the single quote inside the string with **two** single quotes, and surround the string with single quotes:

```
insert into dbo.AccountTypes (AccountTypeId, AccountTypeName)
values (1, 'Partner''s Capital A/c')
```

Answer (score 3):

Option 1 : Use '' for ' (preferred)

```
insert into dbo.AccountTypes (AccountTypeId, AccountTypeName) values (1, 'Partner''s Capital A/c')
```

Option 2 : Set quoted identifier off

```
SET Quoted_Identifier OFF 
insert into dbo.AccountTypes (AccountTypeId, AccountTypeName) values (1, "Partner's Capital A/c")
SET Quoted_Identifier ON
```

MSDN Link for [Quoted_Identifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx)